# Renaming Docusign Certificate of Completion

Tags: php, csv, docusignapi

So I don't have much hope for this, but here it goes.  I am using DocuSign Connect to push envelope data and documents to my http listener.  Is there any way to rename the Certificate of Completion to where it does not have the envelope id appended to the end of the name?

I ask because as our listener pulls the XML file, parses it and writes the PDFs to separate files, I'm having it create a folder named after the envelope id and placing them in the folder with our CSV file. We're having Oracle grab all the PDFs when Filer reads the CSV file, but when it (Filer) hits the Certificate, the name is too long (36 character limit) and it errors out. We have one possible workaround, but I thought I would ask to see if there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was having trouble with modifying the XML file and instead, since we are just storing the PDFs in a database, I decided to just modify the name in my loop for creating the PDFs. My modified code is as follows:

```
//Loop to print out each PDF to separate file
$oldcertname = "CertificateOfCompletion_" . $xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID. ".pdf";
$newcertname = "CertificateOfCompletion.pdf";
foreach($xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF as $value) {
    if($value->Name == $oldcertname) {
        $value->Name = $newcertname;
    }
    $binary = base64_decode($value->PDFBytes);
    file_put_contents($xml->EnvelopeStatus->EnvelopeID . "/" . $value->Name, $binary);
}
```

It works, so thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are in charge of writing out the actual file, correct?  You can set up a renaming function to take whatever the pattern is and rename it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify the file name that the DocuSign Connect service sends out, but three workarounds I can think of so far:

```
1.  Have a script rename the file to a shorter name before it's parsed.
2.  Make an API call to retrieve the envelope certificate.
```

The first option is probably easiest and maybe the workaround you had already thought of.  If you just rename the file to something shorter that should work for your needs.

For #2, the nice thing about DocuSign Connect is that since the platform is pushing data to you instead of you pulling it from the system it does not count towards your hourly api call limit, however that's a very high limit that's tough to reach (1000 calls per hour per account).  [API Walkthrough #6](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeDocuments) shows how to download envelope documents, you can modify it to just download the certificate using its URI.  There is also this page from the REST API Guide which explains how to do so:

```
http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Get Envelope Documents and Certificate.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%20API%20References%7C_____52
```